# gps location in blackberry using android app

Tags: android, gps, location, blackberry-10

My android app can't able to detect GPS location in blackberry devices. If any of you guys have any ideas to detect location in blackberry using android app please help me.

Comment: Is it concerning blackberry 10 or Android ?

Comment: @dvhh, BlackBerry 10 also supports Android applications, so both I suppose.